# What is the difference between "model" and "method"

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I am not sure which forum to ask this question since the answer may change depending on the scientific area.

I am analysing some time series using linear regression. I predict data using the linear function that is obtained from fit. How can I name the linear function that is used to predict data; linear method or linear model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have made is a linear model.  You have made a linear regression that you are using predict future outcomes.

Further information is [on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model), specifically:

> Ordinary linear regression predicts the expected value of a given unknown quantity (the response variable, a random variable) as a linear combination of a set of observed values (predictors). This implies that a constant change in a predictor leads to a constant change in the response variable (i.e. a linear-response model).

There are a number of links at the bottom of that page.

I hope this helps